# how to send a multi-part POST with curl without knowing total size of input

Tags: http, curl, libcurl, live-streaming, alexa-voice-service

I am working on a project which involves sending voice over http stream, i am currently using CURL for my Http backend. I see that if i need to use **"Transfer-Encoding: chunked"** i need to mention the total stream size/**"Content-length:"** . I am currently waiting for the stream to complete from which i will know the total content size . which works but is causing significant delay . i would like to know how can i upload the data in chunks without knowing the total content length of the input.

> curl_formadd(&formpost,    &lastptr,   CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "audio",
>     CURLFORM_CONTENTTYPE, MULTI_PART_CONTENT_TYPE_AUDIO,
>     CURLFORM_STREAM, &(*(aBufffer)),
>     CURLFORM_CONTENTSLENGTH,bufferSize, 
>     CURLFORM_END);

the documentation for "CURLFORM_STREAM" specifies that it is mandatory to specify "CURLFORM_CONTENTSLENGTH" . I need to use "CURLFORM_STREAM" because my buffer is big and I want curl to call "CURLOPT_READFUNCTION" to post the remaining data.

Comment: HTTP is a poor protocol for streaming, most streaming solution over http are basically polling a playlist containing small (~10sec) chunk of the media. the list is updated with the fresh list of encoded chunk. for more "realtime" streaming look for the "RTP" protocol

Comment: @dvhh the server is not in my control, all my voice queries are typically less than 10 seconds . Also the server expects the data over http post (multipart request).

Comment: @DanielStenberg this code is for amazon alexa and alexa servers expect the data to be sent in multiform data, also the data is to be sent in real time so as to reduce the latency in response. Last night i tried sending the multiform data without the "Content-length"  , the upload to server is successful and I am even getting the response from server , but I am getting CURL_RECV_ERROR on performing "curl_multi_info_read" on the multi handle.

Comment: @DanielStenberg any tips ?

Answer (score 0):

looking at the http request header specification for [content-length](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13) and about the [message body](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.3) indicate that this header could be optional for `POST` request as long as the `Transfer-Encoding` header is specified.

The server would look for a message body if either one of the header is present.

The problem is that you would have to find a way to figure out on the server if the message have been fully received.

Comment: hi @dvhh , i have updated my query with snippet of my code, since i am using "CURLFORM_STREAM" according to the documentation [https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_formadd.html]  i need to specify the contents length.

Answer (score 0):

Tell libcurl to do the POST using chunked encoding by setting the header. See example below. You can then simply lie and set `CURLFORM_CONTENTSLENGTH` to some non-zero value since libcurl won't pass on a `Content-Length:` in its request anyway.

```
struct curl_slist *headerlist =
   curl_slist_append(NULL, "Transfer-Encoding: chunked");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);

/* pass in the created formpost data */
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, formpost);

/* send the entire thing away */
curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

Comment: I tried giving a false value for the "CURLFORM_CONTENTSLENGTH" , even after successfully downloading the response from the server , the "curl_mult_perform" fails to change the "still_running" flag because of which my application hangs .
` do {
        ....
          mc = curl_multi_perform(multi_handle, &still_running);
       ....
       } while(still_running);`

Comment: Now you're venturing into debugging territory and we have too little info to go on. Not to mention that it isn't strictly an answer to the question anymore...

Comment: Sorry for not being informative. I tried the same code (mentioned in the question) once by populating **correct** value in the "CURLFORM_CONTENTSLENGTH" and once with **false** value in the "CURLFORM_CONTENTSLENGTH" . In the former case the curl_multi_perform would properly function reducing the number of handles after the download is complete, but in the latter case the number of handles wouldn't reduce.  PS: Thanks for the CURL library.

Comment: I propose you write up a full example that reproduces this case and then you submit an issue in the [curl issue tracker](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues) or to the [curl-library mailing list](https://cool.haxx.se/mailman/listinfo/curl-library).

Comment: I submitted and issue on curl issue tracker with pseudocode (https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/1013) . Thanks for your help looking forward for your feedback.